# Logitech g hub script stop as soon as i release

Tags: lua, mouse, logitech, logitech-gaming-software

Is it possible to make the code stop running as soon as I release mouse button 1 instead of having to to wait until the loop is finished?

```
EnablePrimaryMouseButtonEvents(true);
function OnEvent(event, arg)
  if IsKeyLockOn("capslock")then
    if IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then
      repeat
        MoveMouseRelative(-69,99)
        Sleep(133)
        MoveMouseRelative(11,91)
        Sleep(133)
        MoveMouseRelative(-109,84)
        Sleep(133)
        MoveMouseRelative(-86,75)
        Sleep(133)
        MoveMouseRelative(1,64)
        Sleep(133)
        MoveMouseRelative(33,56)
        Sleep(133)
        MoveMouseRelative(58,47)
        Sleep(133)
        MoveMouseRelative(75,39)
        Sleep(133)
        MoveMouseRelative(84,29)
        Sleep(133)
        MoveMouseRelative(83,18)
        Sleep(133)
        MoveMouseRelative(75,20)
        Sleep(133)
        MoveMouseRelative(60,36)
        Sleep(133)
        MoveMouseRelative(33,49)
        Sleep(133)
        MoveMouseRelative(3,55)
        Sleep(133)
        MoveMouseRelative(-32,69)
        Sleep(133)
        MoveMouseRelative(-55,64)
        Sleep(133)
      until not IsMouseButtonPressed(1)
    end 
  end
end
```

so even if i click left mouse I have to wait until the loop finishes so im wondering if theres a way for the program to stop the moment i let go of left mouse

Answer (score 0):

For a more responsive script you need to tighten the loop.

You are repeating the same functions(`MoveMouseRelative` and `Sleep`) a lot in the loop body. if you simplify the loop body you can have it check the release condition after each `Sleep`

```lua
EnablePrimaryMouseButtonEvents(true);
function OnEvent(event, arg)
  if IsKeyLockOn("capslock")then
    if IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then
      local positions = {             -- Move `MoveMouseRelative` args to an 2d array.
          {-69,99},
          {11,91},
          {-109,84},
          {-86,75},
          {1,64},
          {33,56},
          {58,47},
          {75,39},
          {84,29},
          {83,18},
          {75,20},
          {60,36},
          {33,49},
          {3,55},
          {-32,69},
          {-55,64},
      }
      local index = 1
      repeat
        MoveMouseRelative(positions[index][1], positions[index][2])        
        Sleep(133)
        index = (index % #positions) + 1 -- loop index when it reaches the array length.
      until not IsMouseButtonPressed(1)
    end 
  end
end
```